# Error during initialization of VM - Java

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, debian, clion

My PC was working fine until a restart, when I try to open either `Intellij` Idea or `Clion` I am getting errors regarding initialising `Java VM's`.

Idea error:

> **Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object**
>
> **Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object**

Clion error:

> **Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object**
>
> **[YourKit Java Profiler 2014 build 14112] Log file: /home/colin/.yjp/log/clion10-6619.log
>   14112 - 0.001: warning: `deprecated`option disablej2ee ignored; use probe_off=* or probe_disable=* options instead
>       Error occurred during initialization of VM
>       java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object**

The output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` (the dir does exist):

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75
```

Output of `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

I've tried reinstalling Clion and it made no effect either.

Comment: I'd reinstall the JDK. If multiple java-based tools are complaining, then it's most likely that's the issue. There was an 80 update for java 7; is it possible that you rebooted while it was silently updating?

Comment: The restart was about an hour ago this morning, would the be along the correct time frame?

Comment: just a guess: try to change `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre`

Comment: With that `JAVA_HOME`, though, it's not the system installed version of the JDK that you're using - if it was then it would be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`; and running `java -version` is referencing the system version of java. I'd try unsetting JAVA_HOME in a terminal window and launching idea from there and see if it works; or setting it to reference the system version of the JDK; but it sounds like you've got some bogosity on your system